Android Dark Mode: White Background Appears Behind Keyboard During Transition
Hello CodenameOne Team,
I'm developing a cross-platform app using Codename One, and I'm encountering an issue specific to Android. When the keyboard is triggered to open in dark mode, a brief white background appears behind the keyboard as it transitions into view. This disrupts the dark mode experience and doesn't look seamless.
Here’s a video showing the issue:
Video
How can I prevent the white background flash behind the keyboard during its transition on Android? Is this an issue with Codename One, Android system behavior, or something I need to configure in the Android manifest or theme?
Best Regards,
Oscar

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] that exhibits the problematic behavior. Make sure to reduce it first to only consist of what is strictly necessary to reproduce the issue, not just a code dump of your app. Also, please convert the video into a GIF (there are various online converters) so it can be uploaded directly on Stack Oveflow and integrated and inlined into the question. This way the information won't be lost if the current link rots over time. And finally, why did you direct the question to "CodenameOne Team"? Are you sure you posted on the intended platform?

I suggest trying to add a colors.xml file as suggested here. I'm not sure if it will impact the background of the keyboard which is why I'm not submitting it as an answer.
